# Visual Studio 2010: How to draw a multiobject in a UML sequence diagram?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

When "a client interacts with the elements of a collection, you can use a multiobject" ([src](http://www.tracemodeler.com/articles/a_quick_introduction_to_uml_sequence_diagrams/)), drawn like so:

[image: MultiObject]

In my Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, I have no option to make a "participant" part of a collection. See this screenshot featuring part of my UML drawing board to the left and all available settings in the properties window to the right:

[image: MultiObject]

So, how do I draw a MultiObject in VS 2010?

Comment: Random guess, since I don't have it: Change the type to `student[]`, since `student` isn't a collection?